# Creating mysql temporary table in php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a temporary table in the laravel code, insert values and print something on the front end. But my temporary table is not creating.

```
$temEmployee = DB::insert(DB::raw("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpEmp(
                tmpid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
                NIC varchar(100),
                Designation varchar(100),
                WorkPlace varchar(100),
                Initials varchar(100),
                LastName varchar(100),
                DOB DATE,
                Mobile varchar(10),
                FirstAppoinment DATE,
                DutyAssumeDate  DATE
            )"));
```

Is there any issue with my code?

Comment: you get any error? exception in error/laravel.log

Comment: You should use DB::statement method instead DB::insert

Comment: It doesn't give any error. but doesn't work though.

Comment: "Is there any issue with my code?" Do you really want to insert a SQL statement into a table or execute the SQL statement?

Comment: Yes, I need to execute this query

Comment: How did you see that it doesn't work?

Comment: When I check my local database, this temporary table has not been created. And rest of my code doesn't work and does not give any result.

Comment: A temporary table is only visible within the current session (= the HTTP request). So you can't see the table in a tool like phpMyAdmin. What are you trying to achieve with this table?

Comment: Actually I want to create a temporary table. Then update two columns separately by using another table's column under some conditions and view in a report.

Comment: Tharaka Dilshan's answer works for me. What happens when you run `DB::select('select * from tmpEmp');` directly after creating the table? Does the query work?

Answer (score 1):

Use `DB::statement();` instead of `DB::insert();` to execute `create table query`

```
$temEmployee = DB::statement("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tmpEmp(
            tmpid INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            NIC varchar(100),
            Designation varchar(100),
            WorkPlace varchar(100),
            Initials varchar(100),
            LastName varchar(100),
            DOB DATE,
            Mobile varchar(10),
            FirstAppoinment DATE,
            DutyAssumeDate  DATE
        )");
```